# Magic Squares at the beginning of 20th century

Tags: mathematicians, resource-recommendation

I am doing research on the Ottoman Engineer and Mathematician Aram Margossian (1853-?) (in Turkish sources Margosyan is also used) He published a book, De l’ordonnance des nombres dans les carrés magiques, on Magic Squares in 1908 in France. He also published various papers, in France, on "recreational mathematics" on Euler Squares, Latin Squares etc. I have found the titles of 3 papers up until now, dated 1912, 1931,1936. I did some research on BnF Gallica, Zentralblatt, Mathscinet. Not much is known about his life; there is a paper in Turkish that summarizes a calculus book that he has written in Ottoman Turkish and there is some biographical information there. In his 1936 paper he gives Vienna, Austria, as his address. He has been cited by well-known mathematicians of the time like Maurice Kraitchik.

I am interested in finding out the state of the art about Magical Squares at the beginning of the 20th century.

Also I am trying to find out the PhD advisor of
Edward Fleisher
PhD thesis N. Y. University 1935
On Euler Squares
Advisor unknown ( Math Genealogy Project)

In his thesis Fleisher refers to the 1912 paper of Margossian.

Alp Eden, Turkey

Comment: Wikipedia has some references in the [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Europe_after_15th_century), apparently magic squares were much researched at the end of 19th century.

Comment: You didn't say whether you have a copy of the 1908 book, but in case you don't, [a copy is at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/delordonnancede00marggoog). Regarding "Magical Squares at the beginning of the 20th century", see [**Magic Squares and Cubes**](https://archive.org/details/magicsquarescube00andrrich) (1908) and [**Mathematical Essays and Recreations**](https://archive.org/details/mathematicalessa00schurich) (1898; see pp. 39-63). Incidentally, if you're [this person](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=2047), then I vaguely recall you when I was at IU (1982-84).

Comment: Regarding Edward Fleisher, he was born 22 April 1884 (see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=KLigAAAAMAAJ&q=%22On+Euler+Squares%22+Fleisher)) and he died 8 July 1960 ([see middle of p. 318 in Amer. Math. Monthly 68 #3, March 1961](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2311498)) and based on some results I'm getting by googling, I believe his dissertation is dated 1934 (probably 1934 is the date on the title page) and 1935 is the "official year" he received his Ph.D. degree. **(continued)**

Comment: I haven't been able to find  Fleisher's Ph.D. advisor(s), but perhaps someone with [access to ProQuest](https://dissexpress.proquest.com/dxweb/results.html?QryTxt=&By=&Title=&pubnum=7317865) can obtain a copy of his dissertation and look there.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I looked at it. There is no advisor name on the title page or somewhere else, nor is it apparent from the intro and references. Of recent works he praises McNeish's Euler Squares in 1922 Annals of Mathematics, Schonhardt's  *Uber lateinische Quadrate und Unionen* in 1931 Crelle is the latest cited.

Comment: Here is Fleischer's paragraph on Margossian:"*A. Margossian, Les Carres d'Euler, Nancy Secretariat de la Revue Sphinx - Oedipe (1912), Supplement, sets up a somewhat mechanical method of constructing Euler squares of degree 2, and
shows that a square of order six cannot be constructed by his
method. He fails to prove that every Euler square can be constructed by his method and hence his results are inconclusive.*"

Comment: I do have a copy of the book and I am reading it. Yes I was at IU Bloomington  between 1981-1989.

Comment: I also used Proquest and obtained the phd thesis of Edward Fleisher. No name of advisor is mentioned there. He worked in Brooklyn most of his academic career. He seems to have been active in AMS.